# How to embed markdown documentation inside a working code with C type syntax for commenting?

Tags: comments, markdown, literate-programming

Basically I want to write one piece of text which qualifies both as a working code and MarkDown (preferably GitHub flavor) for documentation. The language I'm using has C form commenting `\\` for rest-of-line and `/* ... */` for multi line comments. So far what I can do is:

```
/* --> start with multi line comments 
here some markdown text
# heading
 * list

end markdown section with
<!--- */ // -->
or
[//]: # (end of comment block --> */ // <-- inline comment)

_-_-indented code
_-_-_-_-more indented code
```

The issues are:

- the first `/*` still showing in the documentation
- I can't use the proper multiline code block ```` ``` ... ``` ````. I have to indent the code parts once more than what is required. Also the syntax highlighting doen't work in this format AFIK.

I would appreciate if you could help me know first how to solve above issues. and Secondly if there is any better way to do this?

Comment: This is a great question. I want to do something similar for easy literate programming. But one of the big issues I have is with how to deal with shebangs. And other boundary condition issues. The answer here is a good starting point though it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have  a proper solution now with colapsible / foldable code section:

````
/*

This is the markdown **text** 

used for documentation

<details>
  <summary>Click to see the source code</summary>

``` scilab 
*/
This is the
  actual code
  which will 
be executed
/*
```

</details>

<!--- */ // -->
````

which will be rendered as:

> 

/*

This is the markdown **text**

used for documentation

```html
*/
This is the
  actual code
  which will 
be executed
/*
```

> 

The collapsible section makes sure that the documentation is clean and readable. you may see the final result [here on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/fef4860d2ba440ee5952538f4db43e52). I used the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab). Now there are a bunch of `/*`s and `*/`s which would be nice to get ride of. Next step would be to modularize the MarkDown document into different files as I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153499/using-html-to-include-import-merge-markdown).

**P.S.** Implementation of the same idea using AsciiDoc [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/atom-asciidoc-preview/issues/200#issuecomment-473575038).

Comment: I think the solution will depend on which Markdown parser is being used (because of the handling of the embedded HTML for instance), but glad you got something working for you.

Comment: true. this only renders on github and vscode, but not Stackoverflow and Typora.

Comment: I was able to innovate on this slightly by being able to properly hide the initial `*/` showing in the code blocks, and to be able to show `//` or `////////////` at the beginning of the file (which is ok since you can use it like decoration) but it seems inescapable to have those at the ends of code blocks, which I can't stand... This makes me kinda sad because otherwise it's pretty capable.