# How I use plantuml in the c file and view it on gitlab repo like .md file

Tags: c, gitlab, plantuml, editor.md

I want to use plantuml in the .c file in my project. I also want to view the c file, just as I viewed the .md file in the GitLab repo at the link below.

[View .md file buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMMaD.png)

If it is possible, how can i do this?

Comment: You don't. The `\`\`\`tag` is Markdown that formats in fixed font with syntax-highlight for `tag` language (`platnum1` in you case). On gitlab or github, `.c` files are not interpreted to contain markdown. The format segment is closed by `\`\`\`` without any `tag`.

Comment: when I reviewed the gitlab document, it talks about acceptable file types in the the languages.yaml file. Is it possible for me to make adjustments there and implement it in my own gitlap repo?

Comment: There I can't help. But, if I had that question, I would e-mail (or contact) one of the github devs and see if that is possible. If you have been through the documentation carefully, and it isn't there, then it's likely not something that is available for a user to do on that site. It's worth asking those that handle that site.

Comment: Possibly related (duplicate) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144543/how-to-embed-markdown-documentation-inside-a-working-code-with-c-type-syntax-for